# Python allows assigning tuple to function (xticks of pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples

I have accidentally assigned a tuple to a pyplot function (that is xticks) and the function became a tuple. Restoring its previous type as a function was not possible. Is this normal or is it considered as an issue ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline 

print mpl.__version__
# Version : 1.5.1

br = (1.0,2.0,3.0)
brand = ('Ford','Audi','Wolskvagen')
count = (100,2000,10000)
plt.xticks((1,2,3),('Ford','Audi','Wolskvagen'))

plt.scatter(x = br,y = count,c = col,s=count)

print type(plt.xticks)
#<type 'function'>

plt.xticks = ((1,2,3),('Ford','Audi','Wolskvagen'))
print type(plt.xticks)
#<type 'tuple'>
#Now, I can't use xticks function any more...
```

Comment: Well you're overriding a module variable. Module variables are writeable. Variables are writeable. There are no protected variables in Python. The closest thing is the namespace convolution of internal instance variables, which start with a `__method_name`, and become `_Class__method_name` outside the instance.

Comment: Thus, I understand that in order to restore it I would need to restart python ?

Comment: You can also reload the module. I'll give a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, there is no such thing as a protected variable. You can write variables in the current namespace, to a module, with only a few exceptions (builtin types that are not subclassed, as well as any class that defines `__slots__` (thanks Alex Hall) are the main exceptions).

For example:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> x = namedtuple('x', 'a b')
>>> y = x(1, 3)
>>> y.a = 3
AttributeError: 'X' object attribute 'a' is read-only
>>> a.t = 3
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 't'
```

This is only true for a few built-in types, as well as classes that override `__setattr__` in a specific manner, or that use properties with no property setter. The general rule is, anything can be written to, whether it's a class, module, function, etc. Yes, functions.

```
>>> def a(x):
...     pass
>>> a.b = 1
>>> a.b
1
```

So, how do you fix an error if accidentally overwrite a variable in a module you imported? Either, restart the Python interpreter or reload the module.

**Python2 Reloading**

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.xticks = 5
>>> plt = reload(plt)
>>> plt.xticks
<function matplotlib.pyplot.xticks>
```

**Python3 Reloading**

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import importlib
>>> plt.xticks = 5
>>> plt = importlib.reload(plt)
>>> plt.xticks
<function matplotlib.pyplot.xticks>
```

Comment: Any class which defines `__slots__` directly doesn't allow setting of any attribute name not in it. `namedtuple` has `__slots__ = ()`.